# Is .net 1.1 supported on Windows Server 2008

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008

We're having an issue.

We have the majority of our code written in .net 1.1 (including asp.net).

We're told that Microsoft do not support .net 1.1 on Windows Server 2008.

The bit we're really confused on is that it's apparently it's only Asp.Net 1.1 that isn't supported on Server 2008.

Our question is, what signifies Asp.net 1.1 is it just the System.Web namespace?

We'd like to get onto Server 2008 (well IIS7 really) asap and if we only have to re-write the Asp.net stuff and not all our business layer and data access layer it'd be much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.net 1.1 is not configured out of the box, but it can be done.  Its really an IIS7 thing, not so much of a Windows Server 2008 thing.

Here is an article about how to configure it:
http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/06/02/installing-asp-net-1-1-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008.aspx

As far as upgrading to 2.0.  It all depends on you code and if you used any features that have been depreciated.  If you were developingin VS2003, opening the projects in VS2008 can converrt it, and then you can easily target .net fx 2.0.  Most issues will be seen at compile time.  Most changes are trivial, and can be changed in a few lines of code.  There are also web.config changes that you may need.

Answer (score 1):

We're running ASP.NET 1.1 applications on Windows Server 2008, so it's certainly possible. I believe you just need to install .NET 1.1 manually, but I can't give details as I didn't handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you're going to have to rewrite anything? It's pretty much just "convert and test".

---

**[.NET 1.1 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=262D25E3-F589-4842-8157-034D1E7CF3A3&displaylang=en):**

> ASP.NET is supported only on the
>   following platforms: Microsoft Windows
>   2000 Professional (Service Pack 3
>   recommended), Microsoft Windows 2000
>   Server (Service Pack 3 recommended),
>   Microsoft Windows XP Professional, and
>   Microsoft Windows Server 2003 family.

Comment: Not a very helpful comment, unless all he has is a single simple application.

Comment: I've done a conversion, and had no problems. I haven't heard that there ae many breaking changes, either. He's not looking forward to a rewrite here.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, sometimes, its not just a "convert and test".  For example, we have a "legacy" .NET 1.1 app that uses Web Service Enhancements 1.0 (WSE 1.0).  WSE 1.0 is not supported in .NET 2.0 and above.